# Ubuntu 20.04 KeyRing Annoyance

Tags: keyrings, gnome-keyring

As an experiment I installed 20.04.1 and selected 'Auto-Login', thinking I'm the only one who would access the platform. Apparently this triggers the Key-Ring-Loop since it isn't part of the auto-login process. Not here to ask how the Ring password got changed but it has, and none of the answers here show how to fix the issue without knowing the current password. I can delete it, but there goes any password management for 'some applications'. Oh, and disabling auto-login doesn't sort it either. What a fun enhancement. At least it isn't called Single Signon.

I have, happily, found the perfect solution, all on my own. I formatted the HDD and re-installed 20.04.1 and carefully avoided the whole auto-login scenario. Luckily this is a single-user, single-purpose platform so I only lost an hour.

Yes, I'm a noob. I admit it. But seriously, it shouldn't be this difficult, and based on what I've read there IS no other solution. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hello. You may want to update and upgrade your system. You list your system as 20.04.1 and an up to date system is 20.04.4

Comment: As written, this seems more like a rant --blaming Ubuntu for your own choices-- than a real question. It could easily be rephrased into a useful question that would benefit others.

Answer (score 1):

You must understand what a keyring it. It is a password protected store to store other passwords and credentials. It is independent from login in to your system.

On a default install, Ubuntu sets up that keyring with a password, the same password you selected for your user account. When giving your credentials on the login screen, the keyring is automatically unlocked using the password provided. With autologin, one does not provide a password. The keyring is not automatically unlocked.

To avoid the password of the login keyring, one can set the password of the keyring to blank. This takes 10 seconds, so far less than the "perfect solution" you have found. Of course, this further decreases the security already introduced by opting for autologin. However, a user choosing autologin could still prefer to keep the password for the keyring. So every user can configure in the preferred way.

To set the password of the "login" keyring to blank:

1. Open "Passwords and Keys" (`seahorse`).
2. Right-click "Login" under "Passwords" in the left pane.
3. Enter your current login password - this is the password that also automatically was assigned to the "login" keyring. Click the "Continue"  button.
4. In the "Choose a now password for the logon..." dialog that appears, leave both fields for the password and the confirmation empty, and click "Continue"
5. Confirm the warning message that appears.

Comment: I'm also trying to stop the kingring password question while using auto-login.  I tried the --unlock option, I then tried just the Enter key multiple times, nothing seems to do anything except ^C which stop the command.

How do I set an empty password?

Comment: @LarryM I actually did not refer to an --unlock option in my answer.

Comment: okay, then how?

Comment: @LarryM I added specific instructions